# Abstract away a compound identity value for use in business logic?

Tags: c#, .net, architecture

While separating business logic and data access logic into two different assemblies, I want to abstract away the concept of identity so the business logic will deal with one consistent identity Type without having to understand its actual representation in the data source.

I've been calling this a *compound identity* abstraction for lack of a better term.

Data sources in this project are swappable, various, and the business logic shouldn't care which data source is currently in use. The identity is the toughest part  because its implementation can change per kind of data source, whereas other fields like name, address, etc are consistently scalar values.

**What I'm searching for is a good way to abstract the concept of identity, whether it be an existing library, a software pattern or just a solid good idea of some kind provided in an answer.**

The proposed compound identity value would have to be comparable and usable in the business logic (e.g. bound to a combobox as the tracked value) and passed back to the data source to specify records, entities and/or documents to affect, so the data source must be able to parse back out the details of its own compound ids.

**Data Source Examples:**

This serves to provide an idea of what I mean by various data sources having different identity implementations.

1. A **relational data source** might express a piece of content with an integer identifier plus a language specific code. For example.

   > ```
   >    content_id  language  Other Columns expressing details of content
   >              1  en_us
   >              1  fr_ca
   > ```

   The identity of the first record in the above example is: **1 + en_us**
2. However when a **NoSQL data source** is substituted, it might somehow represent each piece of content with a GUID string  **936DA01F-9ABD-4d9d-80C7-02AF85C822A8** plus language code of a different standardization,
3. And a third kind of data source might use just a simple scalar value.

So on and so forth, you get the idea.

Comment: Should you be able to compare two entities from different data sources? If your entities all got an `IsSameAs` method, would that solve it?

Comment: No need to compare identities from two different data sources as only one will be in place at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the abstraction is best represented by a comparison *method* (like the one required by [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx)) as opposed to something with property semantics.

Your data access layer, which knows the most about what your entity identities mean, could return objects that use appropriate strategies to implement their comparisons: your NoSQL store would return entity implementations that store and compare GUIDs, your relational store would return entity implementations that store and compare their compound keys, and so forth.

Comment: +1 Good thinking. You're right that my identity abstraction is best realized through existing .NET interfaces that lend themselves to comparison and equality checks, and I can piggyback on those. Plus I can provide alternate/custom implementations for the special scenarios. Before posting I had tried hitting the idea with  custom `IIdentifiable` and `IIdentityAdapter` interfaces - I won't go into gory detail but suffice to say I quickly realized those concepts lent themselves to more work, and it just didn't seem smart.  Your way I like better. Simple and straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

Will `dynamic` type work for you?

I think it will work as long as you don't assign ids at the UI/business logic level. Comparison should work.

Comment: +1 I won't lie: I like this. It's funny but I've found myself on the edge of justifying `dynamic` on two separate occasions over the past two weeks, this one included. Each time that I'm sure I'm going to use it, I find there's a suitable solution without. I want to use it. I think the details of my current project implementation don't lend itself as well to dynamic runtime resolution, although implicit equatable and comparable properties of the objects and values will be realized which is good.